# Using Apache HTTP client URIBuilder on Android?

Tags: android, gradle, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying to use a library which depends on Apache's URIBuilder. When I try to run after adding the library dependency in Gradle, I get the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder;
at com.coinbase.api.CoinbaseImpl.getAuthorizationUri(CoinbaseImpl.java:1127)
```

I've tried adding the apache http client as a dependency in Gradle, but then I get an error:

```
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: To avoid name space collision mention in error , you need to add "HTC" or whatever is the three byte suffix apache adds to make name space unique.

Comment: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html  "HC4" = suffix